# Stellar demo wallet is not considering anchor home domain as valid home domain

Tags: stellar.toml

I am using django-polaris package to build anchor for sep24 and basically on my localhost : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/.well-known/stellar.toml", I find my .toml file!
[image]

But, the moment I am trying to connect it with Steller demo wallet, It gives an error like : "localhost:8000 is not a valid home domain, TOML file was not found"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try to host your toml on a HTTPS server, by default the requests performed by the SDKs enforce the usage of TLS/HTTPS. I don't know if the presence of a port number is an issue or not.

Comment: I would assume ports to not work, as you only are supposed to provide a domain and not a host:port combination