# Showing "network error" while adding asset into stellar demo wallet using anchor(sep24)

Tags: stellar-website

Currently I am using django-polaris to build anchor for sep24 and Ngrok to create https server on localhost. But, the moment I try to add asset into stellar demo wallet, Having fetched the asset record successfully, it's showing network error.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is you are trying to add the home-domain with the leading protocol (`https://…`). You should only provide a domain instead a URL.
As asset-information is still fetched, I'd assume
Further the account (`GCU2YPT63CTAAV2MYHEVOTPFEVHQHJV7L3UYE4XBFEQSHAHUJQLWYV6W`) is not funded (neither on testnet nor on public net - but this does not prevent demo-wallet from fetching asset-info.

Did you check, that the SEP-servers are actually reachable? The network error probably stems from the wallet not being able to resolve the toml, respectively the servers defined there.

Comment: Hey @fragmentedreality, Thank you to reply, Initially I tried to add home domain name without adding leading protocol(localhost:8000) but due to unsecure URL I was not able to add asset and got error like:
https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/steller-demo-wallet-is-not-considering-anchor-home-domain-as-valid-home-domain

and, as far as SEP-Server is concerned, toml file is reachable through my localhost: " http://localhost:8000/.well-known/stellar.toml", still I get an error in stellar demo account.